# call elements of an empty array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wonder how I can make an empty array whose elements are callable, because:

```
a = np.empty(4)
```

gives me the following which is not an empty array for real:

```
a = array([  0.   ,   0.   , 431.675, 291.84 ])
```

I do not understand why (please tell me why!) this is happening, but regardless, I tried this:

```
b = np.empty((0,4))
```

and it gives this:

```
b = array([], shape=(0, 4), dtype=float64)
```

which sounds like an  empty array, but its elements are not callable, as:

```
b[0]
```

gives:

```
index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I know I can have an array with whatever elements and then overwrite the values on each element, like this:

```
p1 = [10,20,100,24352435] #instead of p1 = np.empty(4)
p2 = [1,0,0,1]

    for i in range(4):
        if p2[i] == 0:
            p1[i] = int(1)
        else:
            p1[i] = int(0)
```

but the question is what is the point with `np.empty` then?!

Comment: `np.empty` is used to assign memory, it has nothing to do with the array being actually empty... which is dictated by its size being 0 or not.

Comment: Read the doc string: Notes
-----
`empty`, unlike `zeros`, does not set the array values to zero,
and may therefore be marginally faster.  On the other hand, it requires
the user to manually set all the values in the array, and should be
used with caution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`np.zeros`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html#numpy.zeros) instead of `empty`. `empty` creates `n` items, but it does not initialise them to any value. Hence, it's undefined/random.

Because of its undefined-ness, `np.empty` can be more efficient.

```
>>> np.zeros(4)
array([0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So you said "Because of its undefined-ness, np.empty can be more efficient." Could you explain please, what do you mean by more efficient?

Comment: `empty`: "Buy a plot of land." `zeros`: "Buy a plot of land, bulldoze everything on it so you can build from scratch". So, `empty` is cheaper than `zeros` by the cost of bulldozer crew (but you get old shacks and ruins on your plot of land you need to be careful about).